# Use facebook share dialog without sending current activity to background

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developing a real time multiplayer game using google games services and I want to implement Facebook sharing in my app.  I have photo sharing working already, but the way the google games services works is that if the game's activity goes to the background, the player leaves the room and so the game is disconnected.  Is there a way to use the ShareDialog that Facebook makes available in its SDK without putting the current activity in the background?  Can I force it to overlay semi-transparently?

I've tried forcing the FacebookActivity to use the Theme.Dialog style like so but that had no effect.

If the only option is to create my own custom sharing dialog, please provide an example of how to implement it and pass my SharePhotoContent to it.

```
<activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="transparent.text.FacebookActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to integrate facebook sdk in your application.

At first, create a ShareDialog instance in your onCreate method.

```
CallbackManager callbackManager;
ShareDialog shareDialog;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
    // this part is optional
    shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback < Sharer.Result > () {...
    });
}
```

Then show share dialog using the code below.

```
if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
    ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
            .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
            .setContentDescription(
                    "The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
            .build();

    shareDialog.show(linkContent);
}
```

Also handle the callback in onActivityResult.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Hmm.  I guess maybe my question wasn't clear.  I've done all of that and it's working, except the share dialog itself forces my game into the background which breaks it due to the way google games services works.